# Informix - Insert into column datetime year to second

Tags: sql, informix

I use the informix database. I need to insert the current date with current time into a column with the column type "datetime year to second".

Example:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (my_example_date) VALUES( ??? );
```

How does it work?

Comment: `...VALUES (CURRENT)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current` is what you want to use, here a full working example I tested:

```
create table example_table (my_example_date datetime year to second);
INSERT INTO example_table (my_example_date) VALUES( current );
select * from example_table;
```

gives:

```
2023-02-10 09:21:00.000
```